# incompatible types required: int found: java.lang.String (basic programming)

Tags: java, types

I have come across this error a few times, and I try many things to fix it, but I can't seem to find out what is going wrong. here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name1 = scan.nextLine();
        String name2 = scan.nextLine();
        int num1 = scan.nextLine();
        double num2 = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Employee Name:" + name2 + name1);
        System.out.println("Age:" + num1);
        System.out.println("Salary:" + (double)num2);
    }
}
```

And the error that shows up specicfically is:

> [File: /InputExample.java Line: 9, Column: 25] incompatible types required: int found: java.lang.String
>
> [File: /InputExample.java Line: 10, Column: 28] incompatible types required: double found: java.lang.String

Comment: It's because `scan.nextLine();` returns a `String` and you are trying to assign that returned `String` to an `int`. You need `scan.nextInt();` I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading in a String, but want to save it as Integer/Double. Try this:

```
int num1 = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
```

Same goes for Double.

Or as OldCurmudgeon mentioned:

```
int num1 = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: `scan.nextInt();` may be better.

Comment: You can change it in your answer - considered good practice to make your answer the best you can.